# Mapping foreign keys between form templates in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm working with multiple forms in django, say formA, formB, formC, where formB and formC has foreign key to formA. Each form has submit buttons posting request. So I had written a view as follows,

views.py

```
def mainview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'form_a' in request.POST:
        a_form = FormA(request.POST, prefix = "a")
        b_form = FormB(prefix = "b")
        if a_form.is_valid():
            a = a_form.save()
            return render_to_response('myApp/formB.html', {'b_form': b_form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return render_to_response('myApp/formA.html',{'a_form':a_form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    elif 'form_b' in request.POST:
        b_form = FormB(request.POST, prefix="b")
        c_form = FormB(prefix = "c")

        if b_form.is_valid():
            b_form.save()
            return render_to_response('myApp/formC.html', {'c_form': c_form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return render_to_response('myApp/formB',{'b_form':b_form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        c_form = FormC(request.POST, prefix = "c")
        if c_form.is_valid():
            c_form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Added successfully")
        return render_to_response('myApp/formC.html',{'c_form':c_form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    a_form = ProjectForm(prefix = "a")
return render_to_response('myApp/formA.html', {'a_form':a_form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

where form_a and form_b are the name of the submit buttons in template. The above view displays the foreign key as dropdown list. My problem is, i need to have the foreign key as label or hidden value where user should not be allowed to choose the foreign key. It should be automatically mapped from formA to formB and formC.
If I exclude the foreignKey field from display in forms as follows

```
class Meta:
      model = modelB
      exclude = ['fkfield']
```

and set FK as follows

```
if b_form.is_valid():
      b_form.save(commit=False)
      b_form.fkfield = a
      b_form.save()
```

On form_b request.POST, it throws the following error

```
local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

My question is how do i refer a or how do i map the foreignKey to other forms for each POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I got a solution, but not sure whether it is standard or not. Pls, post any other answers which may be better than this. Here's my solution,

Parse, saved form_a variable 'a' while calling the next form as follows

```
if a_form.is_valid()
      aSaved = a_form.save()
      return render_to_response('myApp/formB.html', {'a_form':aSaved, 'b_form': b_form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now the aSaved variable has the model values stored. In template (formB.html), pass id as a hidden input. In its view, retrieve the model using the following statement,

```
modelA = get_object_or_404(ModelA, pk=request.POST.get('id'))
if b_form.is_valid():
     b_form.save(commit = False)
     b_form.instance.fkfield = modelA
     b_form.save()
```

where id is the hidden variable name.
Remember to exclude the fkfield in its form definition.

Answer (score 0):

here this line `a = a_form.save()` exist only inside first condition i.e. `if 'form_a' in request.POST:`
so while executing the second or third condition i.e. for b and c it doesn't have variable name as `a` so it's throwing error - `local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

while you can do same  by, first saving form A to modal A,

then edit form B and C to contain updated hidden value, with same attribute.

Comment: Yep, but even if i declare {global a} outside the mainview function, it throws the same error. Is there anyother solution to map FK

Comment: Can yo pls explain with some sample code to save form A to modal A

Comment: can you save it by ajax? and use response(i.e. foreign key value of a) for form in B and C. saving by ajax will allow you to use different form with different url u don't need to merge them together.

Comment: Okie.. will make a try.